# Android ScrollView fade edge is never shown

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, fade

i'm using a vertical ScrollView in my view but when the view is scrollable the fading edge is not showing. I've added the attributes that control this feature:

```
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_above="@+id/libottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="50dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
   ...
```

Bu it has no effect when i'm displaying on my device (with Android 4.2.2). What should i do?

**EDIT1**

[image]

I've cropped the view, as you can see, in the middle of the picture is the place where the ScrollView ends and where the fade edge should be shown. Below the ScrollView i have another View.

**EDIT2**

Finally i've figured out that it works on Android **4.4.2** but not in **4.2.2**, has it sense???

Comment: ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findById(R.id.scrollview); scroll.setFadingEdgeLength(150);

Comment: @Wannabe, why should he re set the fadingEdgeLength by code? He have already defined it in his xml as you can see above.

Comment: Sorry i've just tried that with no effect on my view... :(

Comment: Oh sorry, must have read over it.

Answer (score 2):

As of Android ICS, the attribute would now be:

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing this xml attribute on your ScrollView?

```
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
```

Comment: I've just tried adding that attribute but i'm not seeing anything and the view is scrollable

Comment: The attribute has changed to "requiresFadingEdge" as of ICS.